# SQL where field like ■

Tags: sql, xml

I have a SQL database where some data has a `■` in it. When I run a like query for that it does't find anything? I need to correct it as it stops the data transforming to xml?

```
WHERE [value] like '%■%'?
```

Comment: I bet you've mixed up different encodings in your client (the code that performs request), in connection or in data

Comment: Does `WHERE [value] like N'%■%'` find anything?

Comment: @MartinSmith - didn't mean to steal your answer, typing on this phone is slow :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE [value] like N'%■%'?
```

Query it as unicode

Answer (score 0):

Some time unicode does not work, so you can follow the below steps

1. Copy the field value and paste it Notepad
2. Copy that special character
3. Paste between the Like statement.

I am sure it will works. Please confirm.